# Galaxy Note3 is not recognized by Odin ("SeAndroid not enforcing: set Kernel")

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, odin, seandroid

My Galaxy Note3 is not recognized by Odin because its stuck in recovery with `SeAndroid not enforcing: set Kernel`. When I reboot into TWRP recovery, it's recognized by the computer but still fails to acknowledge on Odin.

- **Device:** SM-N9005T Samsung Galaxy Note3.
- **Odin Downloader:** 3.10 (I also have version 3.07)
- **Computer:** desktop running Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22SeAndroid+not+enforcing%22

Comment: you probably flashed wrong twrp, now your device stuck on splash screen. the SeAndroid headline seems unrelated to your problem and is misleading. kindly edit your question. if you ask how to [unbrick](https://youtu.be/5xk_UMr_UgM) it would be helpful to list all actions you have done

Answer (score 1):

i think you are mixing up things

Odin requires your device to be booted in download mode, not recovery mode. if you are in twrp you must leave revovery mode, you can reboot into bootloader from twrp menu. other method to boot into download mode is button combination Volume Down + Home + Power. then select Continue with Volume Up

SeAndroid not enforcing is just a info message which tells you everything is all right. for full access to partitions TWRP requires kernel which allow setting selinux permissive. if SeAndroid is enforcing it would prevent TWRP from working properly

side note: whatever you want to flash from Odin, you could do from twrp command line, too. twrp has full access to all partitions and skilled user can raw write partition images with adb push or dd

Comment: this answer is assuming you pass the SeAndroid not enforcing screen and twrp boots normal